# JSQMessages How to send a location media message

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I use the follow code to send a JSQMessage with location, I dont have any error but the message doesnt show in view.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    var latestLocation: CLLocation = locations[locations.count-1]


    let loc: JSQLocationMediaItem = JSQLocationMediaItem(location: latestLocation)

    loc.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = true

    let locmessage: JSQMessage = JSQMessage(senderId: self.senderId, senderDisplayName: self.senderDisplayName, date: NSDate(), media: loc)

    messages.append(locmessage)

    self.finishSendingMessageAnimated(true)

}
```

And

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageBubbleImageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource! {

    let factory = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory()

    if messages[indexPath.row].senderId == senderId {
       return factory.outgoingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor(UIColor.lightGrayColor())
    } else {
       return factory.incomingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor(UIColor.greenColor())
    }

}
```

No problem for other type of messages (photo and video).

Who can help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you reloaded the collectionView? If you find a solution please post it as an answer, thank you